# How to reduce a google search URL to an anonymized version

Tags: google-search, privacy

If I enter a search term in DuckDuckGo I get a pretty simple url and query string

https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+tips&atb=v1-1&ia=videos&iax=web

[image: duck duck go search results]

If I do the same in google I get a boatload of query string bloat, which I've anonymized with characters `X`, `Y`, `Z`, and `K`.

`https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX&source=hp&ei=YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY&q=python+tips&oq=python+tips&gs_lcp=ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=KKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKKK&uact=5`

[image: google search results]

- If I just pasted a search result url generated by google would that leak individual details that are not anonymmous?
- Is there some subset of query string pairs that would make a functional sharable search url like duck duck go's? (which is still functional even after chopping off the last key value pairs: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+tips)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, as your browser, **you must be using Google Chrome**.

### Please follow these steps to create a custom engine for Google Chrome

1. On your address bar, type `chrome://settings/searchEngines`
2. Click on the `Add` button. A pop-up will appear.
3. Choose a name for your custom engine
4. Assign any keyword as in `=sometext`
5. In the URL field place:

`{google:baseURL}search?q=%s&{google:RLZ}{google:originalQueryForSuggestion}{google:assistedQueryStats}{google:searchFieldtrialParameter}{google:iOSSearchLanguage}{google:searchClient}{google:sourceId}{google:contextualSearchVersion}ie={inputEncoding}`

6. Click on the `Add` button on the pop-up window

**To keep your anonymity when using Google search, on the address bar, type your keyword, hit** **<kbd>`Space`</kbd>** **and type your search**.

As an example, for `python tips`, the URL could be a basic:

```
https://www.google.com/search?q=python+tips&oq=python+tips&aqs=chrome..69i64j69i57.15663j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8
```

[image: How to create a custom search engine in Google Chrome]